# jQuery selector not working. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
console.log($('select[name="Units[]"] option:not(:first:selected)').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Units[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Example1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Example2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Example3</option>
</select>
```

As you can see I don't want to display value 1 and selected value in the console but my program is not working according to my expectation How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `:not(:first:selected)`! ? what do you expect?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understood from the question is that you don't want to display first option and selected option.

You can't use two selector like that. Instead you need to use it like this

```js
console.log($('select[name="Units[]"] option:not(:selected):not(:first)').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Units[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Example1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Example2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Example3</option>
     <option value="4" >Example4</option>
</select>
```

If you only want the selected values, you can get it like this

```js
console.log($('select[name="Units[]"]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Units[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Example1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Example2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Example3</option>
     <option value="4" >Example4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Dude, it works like a charm. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @shahrushabh Glad I helped :)

Comment: On second stage I want to get option value that was selected exclude first please edit the answer with following new selector.

Comment: I tried console.log($('select[name="Units[]"] option:selected:not(:first)'));

Comment: My solution working but I don't want to cover value 1. That solution not covering value 2. Please help me.

Comment: @shahrushabh updates answer to get only selected values